# Centre align social icon divs when bootsrap is responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys below is my code for a social icon section of my footer in bootstrap

html

```
<div class="row ">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5 ">  
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><div class="facebook-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><div class="twitter-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><div class="email-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><div class="googleplus-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
         </div>
</div>
```

sample css

```
.googleplus-roll{
background-image: url('images/googleplus.png');
}

.googleplus-roll:hover {
background-image: url('images/googleplushov.png');
}


.social-roll {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.social-roll:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

The icons looks great on a regular size page but on bootsrap responsive page the icons move to the left. Please help me centre align it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this -

```
<div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">  
            <a class="inline_block" href="#" target="_blank"><div class="facebook-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
            <a class="inline_block" href="#" target="_blank"><div class="twitter-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
            <a class="inline_block" href="#" target="_blank"><div class="email-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
            <a class="inline_block" href="#" target="_blank"><div class="googleplus-roll social-roll"></div></a> 
     </div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.inline_block{
display: inline-block;;
}

.social-roll {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
transition: all ease 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is a Codepen example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKmJE

Comment: Can you choose the answer to be the correct answer for others having the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5 social-icons">  
                <a href="#" class="googleplus-roll social-roll" target="_blank" ></a> 
                <a href="#" class="googleplus-roll social-roll" target="_blank"></a> 
                <a href="#" class="googleplus-roll social-roll" target="_blank"></a> 
                <a href="#" class="googleplus-roll social-roll" target="_blank"></a> 
         </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.social-icons {
    text-align:center;
}

.social-roll {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
      border: 1px solid red;
}

.googleplus-roll{
    background-image: url('images/googleplus.png');
    display:inline-block;
}

.googleplus-roll:hover {
    background-image: url('images/googleplushov.png');
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ky9Jd/)